# how to work with the received data = [object Object]?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the received data = [object Object] and how it works ?
actually I send a post request and I need to get the code page that will come in the browser you can see in the debugger that it comes in, but I can not programmatically get it.

here is the code

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "https://ua-eshop.oriflame.com/iframe/Consultant/OnlineQuickRegistration.aspx",
    dataType: 'script',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    data: date,
    async: true,
    complete: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        var text = data;
        console.log (JSON.stringify (data));

        console.log (data.toString ());

        console.log (data);
    }
});
```

and output from the console

> {"readyState": 4 , "status": 200 , "statusText": "success"}
>
> [object Object]
>
> Object {readyState: 4 , getResponseHeader: function,
>   getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function,
>   overrideMimeType: function ...
>
> there are many functions }

This is what the server returns:

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional / / EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_pageHead"> <title>
Online quick registration
</ title>
```

and so on

this page is necessary to read

Comment: You need to print the status Text??

Comment: I need to get the page

Comment: Why you set `dataType` to `script`?

Comment: Setting `dataType` to `text` may solve your problem.

Comment: only jsonp or script returns the result to the browser

Answer (score 1):

i thing your problem will solve by using any one of these

Try `console.log(data.toSource());`

or `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: console.log(data.toSource());  - error undefined is not function
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
=> {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `complete` option for `$.ajax` instead of `success`.

The first param given to `complete` (what you're naming as `data`) is actually the `jqXHR` object. This is what you're seeing in the various forms of logging you've shown, and is *not* what you want.  (*`[Object object]` is the output of `.toString()` for an object*).

Furthermore, the `complete` method is run after all `$.ajax` functionality and events regardless of the status of the HTTP request it made. This being the case, no response data is passed to it because it may be running after an erred request to the server which would not have resulted in any data.

Switch to the `success` option (find it and read about it on the [`$.ajax` docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). This only runs for a successful request, and the first param it is given is the data from the server.

Having switched to `success` you'll need to iron out whether your request is actually making it to the server and data is being returned. You also need to determine what type of data you're expecting back from the server (HTML, XML, JSON, plain text, etc) and set the `dataType` appropriately (again, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) before proceeding).

**Addendum**

One reason your HTTP request could fail, resutling in `success` not being called, is [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can only request a script or jsonp from a domain which is not the same as where your script is running. When you tell jQuery it's a script, it tries to put it in your page for you--and since what you're requesting isn't a script, it cannot do that. If you tell it "jsonp", the distant end must support the protocol and send back a script with JSON wrapped in a function call. Obviously the distant end does not support it, and only sends back HTML.

You are actually requesting HTML, but could even use plain text. Unfortunately, Same-origin policy will not allow it.

Comment: result html page, I do not know what type of data, the result is only when the type is jsonp or script, if success does not change the result

Comment: See my addendum to my answer. You are running into bigger issues than you thought.

Comment: I decided otherwise through php script but wanted to solve through jquery